# Beginner's Factorial Code

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python and I have a small bit of code that takes the factorial of a user input. I'm trying to understand the logic behind what's going on so I can better understand the process.  Why is it when I change the location of one of my variables the output changes? (I'm using python 2)

```
user_input = input("enter a positive number")

for i in range(user_input):
    product = 1     #the output changes when I move it here instead of above the for loop
    product = product * (i + 1)    
    print(product)
```

Comment: Because in each iteration of the loop, you're setting `product` to 1. If you do that outside the loop, you only set `product` to 1 before the loop is ran the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting

```
product = 1
```

inside the loop, you are re-initializing the total value each iteration of the loop.

If the user were to enter 3, 
It would show `1, 2, 3` because every iteration you are just creating a variable product with the value of 1, and multiplying it by the (iterator +1) which is just (1 * (iterator +1)).

If you put

```
product = 1
```

outside the loop, the total value would only be initialized to 1 at the start, and you would be able to correctly sum the value of the factorial.

If the user entered 3 as the input again, it would show `1, 2, 6` because it will no longer multiply (1* (iterator + 1)) but (previous sum * (iterator + 1))

Answer (score 1):

The loop works like this:

```
user_input = input("enter a positive number")

for i in range(user_input):
    product = 1                  #Set product to 1
    product = product * (i + 1)  #Increase product
    print(product)               #Print the product
```

Every loop the value of `product` will reset back to `1` before doing the calculation.

> Loop 1 
>   product = 1 
>   product = 1 * (1 + 1) = 2 
>   Loop 2 
>  
>   product = 1 
>   product = 1 * (1 + 2) = 3

Answer (score 1):

this isnt going to answer your question ... but I find factorial is easiest to think about recursively

```
def factorial(n):
    #base case if n is 0 or 1 : 0! == 1! = 1
    if n in (1,0): return 1
    #recursive case : otherwise n! == n*(n-1)!
    return n*factorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the loop, that means that each loop iteration, product will be reset to 1. So you end up with the same result as if you ran just the final iteration of the loop. In other words the products don't accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

That's because every time the for loop runs, you're setting:

product = 1

Answer (score 0):

product is reset to 1 in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do.

```
user_input = int(input("enter a positive number"))
product = 1  
for i in range(user_input):
    product = product * (i + 1)    
    print(product)
```

But when you put **product = 1** into loop, every time loop start with product =1 which remove previous production. wokr like this

```
user_input = int(input("enter a positive number")) 
for i in range(user_input):
    product = i + 1   
    print(product)
```